# Thread 3: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, SUBCODE=0xdefe)

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

I'm importing contacts from address book, i got this error when running in iPhone. It's perfectly working in simulator. I got this error when releasing name object. When i comment this **CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(name));** its working fine in device also. In Xcode it showing a memory leak but no crash in device. Please find my code also.

```
// Create an new address book object with data from address book database
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

// Returns all the records in address book and store in array
NSArray * allPeople = (__bridge NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

// Allocate memory for appdelegare mutable array to store contacts as dictinary object
appDelegate.allPeopleDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (id person in allPeople) {

    // Get name of person from address book contacts
    NSString * name = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyCompositeName((__bridge ABRecordRef)(person)));

    // Get phone numbers of person from address book contacts
    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(person), kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    // Create a mutable array to store phone numbers
    NSMutableArray * phoneNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString * phoneNumber;

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {

        // Get each phone number of a person
         phoneNumber = (__bridge NSString *)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i));

        // Add the phone number to phone numbers array and trim the phone number
        [phoneNumbersArray addObject:[self trimThePhoneNumber:phoneNumber]];

        // Release phone number object
        CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(phoneNumber));
    }

    // Create a dictionary object with name and phonenumbers
    NSDictionary * personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:name,phoneNumbersArray, nil];
    //NSDictionary * personDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:name,[self trimThePhoneNumber:phoneNumber], nil];
    CFRelease(phones);

    // Add this dictionary object to mutable array
    [appDelegate.allPeopleDict addObject:personDict];

    // Release name object
    CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(name));// Here i'm getting this error
}
// Release allPeople array object and addressbook object
CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(allPeople));
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__bridge_transfer` instead and let ARC worry about it (or bits of it):

```
// Create an new address book object with data from address book database
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

// Returns all the records in address book and store in array
NSArray * allPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

// Allocate memory for appdelegare mutable array to store contacts as dictinary object
appDelegate.allPeopleDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (id person in allPeople) {

    // Get name of person from address book contacts
    NSString * name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyCompositeName((__bridge ABRecordRef)(person)));

    // Get phone numbers of person from address book contacts
    ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)(person), kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    // Create a mutable array to store phone numbers
    NSMutableArray * phoneNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {

        // Get each phone number of a person
        NSString * phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i));

        // Add the phone number to phone numbers array and trim the phone number
        [phoneNumbersArray addObject:[self trimThePhoneNumber:phoneNumber]];
    }

    // Create a dictionary object with name and phonenumbers
    NSDictionary * personDict = @{
        name : phoneNumbersArray
    };

    CFRelease(phones);

    // Add this dictionary object to mutable array
    [appDelegate.allPeopleDict addObject:personDict];
}

CFRelease(addressBook);
```